# How to set header title after navigatiing to a page in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have used stack navigator in my project and I want to set header title after navigating to a screen . I am doing like this after seeing example .Where ProductListView is a functional component.But it is not changing.

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  ImageBackground,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  AsyncStorage,
View
} from "react-native";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const ProductDetails = ({ navigation }) => {

  return (
    <View flex={1}>

        <Text>Details</Text>

    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});


ProductDetails.navigationOptions = () => {
  title: "test";
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Updated full code

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: Where have you written this code?

Comment: Before exporting the component Like this ProductListView.navigationOptions = {
  title: "Home Product"
};

export default ProductListView;

Comment: What is the actual problem and what do you want is not clear

Comment: actual problem is I want to set header title based on a value I get in my screen useEffect function

Comment: Hi , I have updated full code

Comment: But from where will you send the title as an argument?

Comment: It is a hard coded value now later on I will push the data from API

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the title like this.

```js
ProductDetails.navigationOptions = () => ({
   topBar: {
        title: {
            text: 'My Title'
        }
    }
});
```